# Laravel project uploaded to live server in slash folder, works good on local but not working to live slash folder

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel application working good on `localhost`

Laravel project uploaded to live server in slash folder, works good on local but not working to live slash folder just like `demo.com/app`

Its showing **error** like:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

**I tried-**

changed `.env` file `APP_URL` to `demo.com/app`

I have moved `.htaccess` file from `public` folder to main folder `demo.com/app`

**Current `.htaccess` code ("demo.com/app")**

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Error Message:

> 505 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: just check the permission of the laravel.log file anything else is remain as it is like you don't have to change the APP URL and .htaccess